# LEI windows Service makes the lotus domino server to crash

Tags: lotus-domino

I am facing a problem with the LEI windows Service.

Lotus notes Domino Server is the system component 
LEI - Service

Both are windos service.   LEI is dependant on lotus domino server.

Past few days i am experiencing a weird problem, LEI service was not running, when i started it it makes the lotusnotes domino server to crash.

Comment: Hi balaji.  I'm afraid this question isn't really suitable for Stack Overflow as it doesn't relate to software development.  Since it relates to servers, you may have more luck asking it on http://www.serverfault.com/ instead.  In fact, I've voted to close it as 'belongs on serverfault'; if enough people agree with me it'll be moved over automatically.

Comment: @LukeWoodward This question is utter garbage. Even someone that's never worked with Domino in their life can read it and realize that there are no details other than "I use Domino and it crashes when I start a server". Please **stop** voting to migrate trash. Questions should only be migrated if they are of exceptional quality. In the future, consider voting as "off topic" and **don't** pick a destination site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced several LEI issues in the past which caused domino crashes. 
A few suggestions: 
- does the server crash on a specific activity? What kind of activity? Can the databases this activity uses be accessed? 
- Check the LEI Log (leilog.nsf) when this is corrupt, create a new one. 
- Check your LEI Activities. All activities that were running or scheduled to run when the server crashed should be reset using the "Reset Activity" action (Menue actions - activity administration - Reset activity).
- Logging: Do you use heavy logging? There is an option "Buffer log". I had issues with this when there is very nmuch information to be logged (it causes and OutOfMemory, because the log is buffered and not permanently written to the log document)

Comment: Hi mruhnau,  Thanks for the help!   i managed to resolve the issue. The log file was corrupted and so it was causing the domino to crash when LEI was started.